# How to build a regex that does not allow & (ampersand) character anywhere in a string

Tags: regex

I am new to the ui stuff and need some help on building a regex pattern which does now allow & in a given string at any place. Some examples are

```
tom & tom = don't allow
&tom = don't allow
& tom = don't allow
tom&tom = don't allow
tom tom  &  = don't allow
```

So tried many approached but does not seems to work and fails in one or the other scenario.

My existing regex written by somebody long back is 
`([a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\s-]).{5,30}`. With this existing pattern i have to add my own check to not allow & anywhere in anystring.Tried `([a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\s-])(^[^&]*$).{5,30}` but failed for the scenario string tom & tom .Any suggestions
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to anchor regex on both ends with `^` and `$`, and use `[^&\v]` in the body, like this:

```
^[^&\v]*$
```

Note that this expression also matches empty strings.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/1GVRAZ/3)

Comment: If anyone is wondering why the demo is displaying all valid lines as one capture it's because `[^&]` also matches newline characters. To *properly* view how this would work on individual lines use [`^[^&\v]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/1GVRAZ/2) in the demo instead.

Comment: So i have a existing regex like   ([a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\s-]).{5,30}  which i think allows a-z and A-Z , length in 5-30 length , not sure about the middle one what it does but i have to not allow the & in this scenario.Tried               ([a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\s-])(^[^&]*$).{5,30}  but failed for the scenario string tom & tom .Any suggestions

Comment: @Sam Your regex can match any part of the string because it is missing `^` and `$` anchors. If you give it, say, `hello&world` string, it would match the `hello` part, and stop at the ampersand. If you don't want ampersands anywhere in the entire string, use anchors.

Comment: @Sam when you post your question you should present us all the necessary details so that we can give you a more appropriate answer. Can you add a new section under your existing question and add an edit that includes any additional information so that we can give you that more appropriate answer? Right now your regex is matching (and capturing) any ASCII letter `([a-zA-Z])`, ensuring what follows is any character any number of times followed by either a space or a hyphen `(?=.*[\s-])`, and then matching any character 5-30 times. Without anchoring, you are matching this anywhere in the string.

Comment: edited and corrected the question to provide more details about my scenario.

Comment: @Sam you can use [`^([a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\s-])(?=[^&]*$).{5,30}$`](https://regex101.com/r/1GVRAZ/4) or even more simple is [`^([a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\s-])[^&]{5,30}$`](https://regex101.com/r/1GVRAZ/5)

Comment: @Sam Anchors go outside of everything else in your expression, otherwise they wouldn't "attach" to the beginning or the end of the target string.